# Concept for individual menus with json

Tags: sql, json, database

I'm searching for a database concept for managing a dynamic multilevel menu as JSON Object. Because we have different customers, and the menu is depending on the customer. I'm searching for a database structure to store the following JSON String so that I can edit the structure and create again a json object from the data. How would you realize that? I don't need a complete answer, just an approach.

```
[
      {
        name: 'Dashboard',
        url: '/dashboard',
        writeble: true,
        icon: 'icon-speedometer'
      },
      {
        name: 'Menu1',
        url: '/menu1',
        writeble: true,
        icon: 'icon-puzzle',
        children: [
          {
            name: 'Item1.1',
            url: '/item/item1.1',
            icon: 'icon-puzzle'
            subitem: [
                 {
                   name: 'Subitem 1',
                   url: '/item/item1.1',
                   icon: 'icon-puzzle'
                 }
          },
          {
            name: 'Item1.2',
            url: '/item/item1.2',
            icon: 'icon-puzzle'
          },
          {
            name: 'Settings',
            url: '/settings',
           icon: 'icon-settings'
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly your question, I would use a NoSql DB where every document is your JSON object and the key is the customer Id.